# how to manually install packages from MELPA?

Tags: emacs, melpa

So, I have been trying to install `use-package` by`(package-install 'use-package)` but I keep getting the error `use-package is unavailable`. I have also tried to install other packages but they are also unavailable.

I was wondering if could go to the MELPA page, find the package(eg use-package) and download. Is there a way to configure your `init.el` such that packages can be used/installed without any variation consisting of `(package-install 'use-package)`?

Answer (score 1):

Try `M-x + package-refresh-contents`
Also, use the melpa-stable instead.

```
(setq package-archives '(("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/")))
```

I recommend doing it because You will encounter this error pretty often and manually building those packages each time is a bad thing to do.
Also, `M-x` is `Alt+x`. ( `M` is meta key and in most keyboard, `alt` is the meta key).

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/etikbz/speaking_as_a_package_maintainer_please_do_not/

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out; it is useful given Emac's misbehavior.

As an example consider installing the `use-package`:

```
git clone https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package.git ~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/use-package

cd ~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/use-package

make
```

and then adding this to your `init.el`:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/use-package")
(require 'use-package)

(with-eval-after-load 'info
  (info-initialize)
  (add-to-list 'Info-directory-list
               "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/use-package/"))
```